# When was forwardRef added to ag-grid?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I'm currently using ag-grid@^18 and I'm having problems using renderers / editors. I'm using both classes and functions (hooks) and having trouble with both. The hooks variation has the most success but it's not updating as expected. I'm using this example as a guide:

https://www.ag-grid.com/react-hooks/#hook-cell-editor

The problem is that forwardRefs's ref argument is undefined. Does anyone know when ref started getting passed down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually `ag-grid@18` has react 16.0.0 as a peer dependency and forwardRef became part of react 16.3.0, maybe this is causing issue. One thing you can try is pass `reactNext={true}` to `AgGridReact` component.